# Would a switch be covered by a router's firewall

Tags: networking, router, firewall, switch

I need more Ethernet ports on my home network. Sadly, we already have an old router connected to the main router and we still need more ports.

Would the devices connected to the switch be "protected" by the Main router's firewall? ? Up to this point I have assumed that was the case; but, a co-worker is convinced that is not the case. I believe he is thinking of a situation in which the switch (un-managed) is before an access point.

It would go: modem ==> main router ==> switch ==> old router

Comment: Of course they would be.

Comment: You write "[ I believe he is thinking of a situation in which the switch (un-managed) is before an access point]. "  <-- I am not sure why you think a switch and access point connected to the router make a difference. An access point is or is like a wireless switch.  It's all on the same subnet and the NAT on the router (or a firewall) protects that from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have 3 devices behind your firewall:   The main router [which runs the firewall] , an extra switch , an extra router.

as long as the chain start at one of your main router's LAN ports, note you dont have DMZ enabled on that port, and make sure that your FW rules are solid - and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the network architecture is something along the lines of:

1. Modem
2. Router/firewall
3. Switch
4. Hosts

then yes, all hosts will be protected by the firewall because the firewall sits in between any host and anything not trusted. Note that a lot of consumer "routers" technically are combined gateways, firewalls and possibly switches.

However, if the architecture is more like:

1. Modem
2. Switch
3. Router/firewall
4. Host

(Only one host behind the router)

then only the host that is behind the firewall will be protected by the firewall, because the firewall is not involved in the communications at all for any other hosts.

**The firewall can only protect what logically sits "behind" it,** from the perspective of the source of untrusted traffic. A sanely configured firewall will protect anything that sits behind it, unless you have specifically configured it to do otherwise.

Comment: i'm curious about the configuration of modem->switch->router/firewall->host.  Suppose you had a comp or two connected to the switch. (I haven't done that before).. What's the situation with ip addresses? Would they have to be public IPs? That's interesting I guess you could then port scan one of your own computers (as if from the internet) with that configuration? Would a consumer router be able to handle having a switch connected to its WAN port?  I suppose the Router at the WAN port would have to put the correct MAC on the packet,rather than just sticking the modem's MAC on it(if it has one)

Comment: @barlop From the point of view of the Internet, they would be two separate connections. For that to work your ISP would have to assign you multiple (upstream) IP addresses, and your equipment must be able to handle that situation; you couldn't just put a switch in between your local network equipment and the modem and expect things to work. I have such a setup at home, where I separate different types of traffic already at the modem's LAN ports, meaning that each "side" gets an independent public IP address but from the same ISP. (And before you yell "IP address waste": that is recommended.)

Comment: Yes I understand they have to be public and indeed you have to have them from the ISP. And assuming that is all set up by DHCP for the comps on that switch- computers there getting it by DHCP from ISP. What i'm asking is would a consumer router be able to handle having not just a modem on the WAN end, but a switch and comps there, and such that a comp on your private IP range LAN could access them? And if some consumer routers would some wouldn't, then what would one look for in the spec, for one that would?

Comment: @barlop My small business NAT router handles it just fine, and I don't see why anything else wouldn't. From its perspective the other 'side' of the LAN is really an Internet host on the WAN side that just happens to have a pretty decent roundtrip time. Since this really doesn't seem to be related to this question though, much less my answer to it, if you want to explore that further please ask a separate question about it. I don't mind expanding a little on the setup but comments isn't the place to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of firewall protection.

The firewall on the router is a firewall that prevents traffic from outside the network (internet) to be filtered when reaching the inside of the network (Local Area Network).

The other firewall is on the computer itself, which protects itself from any activity outside of the computer.

Given that the router is the portal between the internet and the Local Area Network, it is sufficiently protecting your network from outside attacks.

However, if an email with virus is passing through, and a client opens the email, it can still cause harm. But the firewall on the router will never protect against that anyway. Because people hear about this kind of vulnerability, it is often misunderstood (as is the case here).

Basically, the firewall on the router is sufficient if the people that work on the network are not stupid enough to open anything they receive. If you have people like that in the network, any protection from getting potential problems on a client computer need to be made. A firewall per computer is a way, but a proper virusscanner locally and on the email server is another way.

If the router is at the inside of the network, extending the amount of clients (as you tell) it will be on the internal side of the firewall, and thus it is protected from the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Anything connected to the LAN-port of a properly configured router will be similarly protected from the outside network no matter whether you connect directly a computer, hub, switch or a router.

Just make sure that the cable connecting to the internet (xDSL/cable modem or the wall) is plugged into the WAN port of the router. Then make sure that all other lan cables coming from the router are connected to LAN-ports (not WAN2 etc). All traffic from subsequent devices will be routed through the router.

Note that if you use VPN, these will expose your private computer to the internet and thus has to be protected by a (software) firewall.

Comment: *"Anything connected to the LAN-port of a properly configured router will be protected from the outside network"* Not strictly true. It's largely true for consumer "routers", but not true for all routers. If it was true for all routers, then we wouldn't need local firewalls.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - In the context of this question I think that statement should be considered correct.

Comment: @Ramhound much better for him to specify that he is talking about NAT Routers and i'm not sure what he might be thinking of for improperly configured NAT router.  It's bad to make a statement that is false in many situations, just because it happens to be true for the routers that most consumers use. An inaccurate statement that doesn't say it's only true for a common 'class' of routers, and speaks as if for all, can make it harder for people to understand technology.

Comment: The questioner himself was more accurate by saying "Would the devices connected to the switch be "protected" by the Main router's firewall?"  <-- I think that would be true for all routers. But it'd be as protected as any comp is plugged into a port. But for how protected that is, you have to consider how the firewall is set. But you still have the NAT.

Comment: I do believe I have mentioned properly configured, and to add: bug free. I understand what you mean, but in all seriousness, a configured router protects from all inbound traffic. It is the outbound based requests and user actions that may be a problem and thus the router does not protect everything, including the user spilling coffee on the keyboard.

Comment: I'd like to add that "assuming the NAT is enabled", but then questions would arise -- what does NAT mean, where can I check, and how is it configured (taking into account DMZ-ports etc.).

Covering all eventualities is impossible. Thus the "assumption of properly configured". :) I stand by my answer even if someone feels that it should be down voted.

Comment: @Wibin to say 'properly configured' is like a get out clause to cover yourself, Similarly specifying 'bug free'. It's not specifying what he should be configuring, what configuration. If you're talking about NAT, then merely having NAT on, getting the private IPs, is all the 'proper configuration' that you may be referring to.

Comment: @Wibin Well, DMZ isn't any default. but yes you have a point that just having NAT isn't necessarily enough. But always better to specify 'cos just saying 'properly configured' is too general to be useful.

Comment: This comment thread going in the wrong tracks. The asker specified that the main router has a firewall. It may not even have any NAT or DHCP, merely a packet inspection firewall which can be considered safe (even if arguably less so). We cannot cover all eventualities, but we can try to answer the question. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15007/discussion-between-barlop-and-wibin).